# Installing tensorflow inside a docker container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow inside my docker container. However, having tensorflow in my requirements.txt or even doing a `RUN pip install tensorflow` gives me the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I can't find how to access tensforflow inside my docker container. I tried to use the tensorflow docker container inside my container by adding the following to my Dockerfile

```
RUN docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow
RUN docker run -it tensorflow/tensorflow
```

but had no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

That's a terminal command. Run this in your terminal:
`docker run -it tensorflow/tensorflow`